# How to call an AJAX function after setting a session variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
/**********************
    User clicks on an album
**********************/
var $curr;
$(document).on('click', 'div#albumlist>a', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $.get('albums.php?aid='+$albumid).done(showThumbs());  // Set the session album ID and refresh thumbnails
});

/**********************
    AJAX Thumbnails
**********************/
function showThumbs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'thumbs.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="<p class='panellabel'>album name</p><div class='panelline'></div>"+output;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="<p class='panellabel'>album name</p><div class='panelline'></div>" + 
                "ERROR " + xhr.status + ": " + thrownError;
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to create a site where the user clicks on an album, a session variable "aid" is updated, and then showThumbs() is called to display the photos in the selected album within a container.

I originally had:

```
$.get('albums.php?aid='+$albumid);
showThumbs();
```

But that yielded the same results.

After viewing the network traffic, it seems that showThumbs() is called *before* the session variable is set. This happens on an intermittent basis. Is there a way to force the AJAX call to wait until the $.get is done before showThumbs() executes?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass your callback, don't invoke, just pass the implementation. Change to:

```
$.get('albums.php?aid='+$albumid).done(showThumbs);
```

or

```
$.get('albums.php?aid='+$albumid).done(function () {showThumbs()});
```

But the second one seems silly.

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm. I'm new-ish to jQuery and JavaScript in general. What's the difference between invoking and passing the implementation?

Comment: So these two statements are equivalent in javascript.  var functionName = function () { stuff }; and function functionName() { stuff };  -- If that makes sense, then think about what the first example looks like. In the first example you're storing the implementation to a variable and you can pass that variable around like any other variable or you can execute it by placing () at the end. That's how callbacks work in general.

Comment: Also, check this out: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

You pass a function reference to `.done()` like this (without the parens after the function name):

```
$.get('albums.php?aid='+$albumid).done(showThumbs);
```

When you put the `()` like `showThumbs()` that executes it immediately rather than just passing a function reference that can be called later.